# Anaconda environment in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, environment, conda

I am trying to use Anaconda environment as an interpreter in Pycharm.

It actually works, but it's extremely slow - even running a single line "hello world" takes like 5 sec.

I guess the reason is Pycharm trying to *activate* the environment before every execution of the script and activation in Anaconda is generally slow (at least from my experience).

The execution speed is ok when using Anaconda root env. or when using virtualenv. Any idea/workaround how to speed it up?

Answer (score 5):

You should not activate the environment on every run.
You need to define the interpreter for the project. It will take a couple of seconds to parse the installed packages in that environment and later it will be fast.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#project-interpreter

I wonder if there is something special in the packages you have in your environment. Five seconds is not normal.

Have you tried creating a new environment from pycharm?

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-environment.html

and later adding the packages that you really need for that project?

Comment: I might be wrong, but the activation is something *Pycharm* does - at least this would explain why python execution when using conda environment takes so long. See here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17739

Comment: The environment is activated when you set the project interpreter and the inspection is triggered. In fact, by selecting the correct project interpreter you will get proper warnings. With respect to the ticket, it seems about special packages that use activate.d Are you using that?

Comment: Special packages - no, at least I'm not aware of that. Yes, it's perfectly possible that my understanding that the process start up delay is caused env activation is wrong. However `conda-wrappers` mentioned in my answer addresses this specific issue and seems to help.

Comment: Some more info - the delay observed when executing a script inside pycharm seems to be equal to the time required to activate conda env. The interpreter is set correctly according to JetBrains manual. Any idea what might be other reasons for the run/debug startup delay?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I'm not the first one experiencing this. A cool guy named Guilherme Melo created wrappers which you can use as an replacement for python interpreter in Pycharm. These wrappers than handle environment activation in a much faster way.

Just follow his advices [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18865#comment=27-1444034).

Basically all you need is to install a package called `conda-wrappers` into you conda environment a then replace the interpreter in Pycharm.

```
conda create -n test python
source activate test
conda install -c conda-forge conda-wrappers
```

Works in Windows too. So instead of `<env>/python.exe` you should select `<env>/Scripts/wrappers/conda/python.bat`.

That said, I consider this to rather be a workaround for a very slow conda activation script - would be nice to have that handled in a first place.